# will it work if i put Google analytics code in an IF statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-analytics

i want to only trigger a page hit once a function has been triggered. so can i do the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function gaCodeParser(parseGAcode){
if(parseGAcode == 'triggerGAcode'){
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxx-xx']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/success-page']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
}
else{
//do nothing
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: `_gaq` should be global because the loaded script uses it.

Comment: so what you're saying is that I should just add the _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/success-page']); in the if statement not all the google code?

Comment: I mean that at least the `var _gaq` should be outside any function.

Comment: _gaq will be unavailable when u call your function gaCodeParser(). include the ga.js code at the top and do the rest

Comment: @Apurv like this: 

  'var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-x']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();  
 function gaCodeParser(parseGAcode){
   if(parseGAcode == 'triggerGAcode'){
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/success-page']);
   }
 }'

Comment: (function() { var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'ssl'; : 'www';) + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); })(); "Put this first and then rest of the code"

Comment: why not you create a separte file and include in the page of yours??

Comment: @Apurv cheers! I'll try both...

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want to capture that ? google analytics will anyway give you efficient metrics like unique views, unique visitors and so on, if you try to fiddle around thier code you will only loose metrics provided by GA. if you still want to go ahead and fork what is given by GA you can still do so but please dont expect GA to give you all metrics.